# jquery object to the string

Tags: jquery

```
$("h2.trigger").click(function(){
            console.log($(this));

            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
            var viewName=$(this).attr('id');

            //display approval list ajax method
            var html="";
```

I'm currently working on a jQuery application and do a `console.log($(this));`

In Firefox it prints

> [h2#vw_hs_hr_wf_admin_data.trigger]    this is a object

We can not take it as a plain string as it returns `Object object`. I would like to assign the `"h2#vw_hs_hr_wf_admin_data.trigger"` as a plain text to a JavaScript variable.

I tried

```
alert($(this).id); 
alert($(this).0);
```

but I have no luck.

Comment: What do you need this for? It seems you want the ID concatenated with the classes, but why?

Comment: want to print "h2#vw_hs_hr_wf_admin_data.trigger" i think this is a object name. why means i want get the current object and put it the php session and get the value lator

Comment: What is the value of an `h2` element? The text?

Comment: value is some dynamic generated table

Comment: And how is this table related to the `h2` element? How do you want to get the "value" given the name/id/whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the attr method: `$(this).attr("id")` ?

Comment: this will return element id only i want full object name 
to print "h2#vw_hs_hr_wf_admin_data.trigger" i think this is a object name. why means i want get the current object and put it the php session and get the value lator

Comment: @Roshan: As IDs have to be unique, this will be fine if you want to access the same element later on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you'd want with this, but this thing makes concatenates the objects properties into what you want. The reason you see it like that in Firefox, is that it does that concatenation internally when presented to the user. 
Markup in my example is this;

```
<h2 id="vw_hs_hr_wf_admin_data" class="trigger">Click me</h2>
<p></p>
```

And then the script does its thing;

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('h2.trigger').click(function() {
            var text = getTagNameIdClass(this);
            alert(text);
        });
    });
    function getTagNameIdClass(obj) {
        return (obj.tagName).toLowerCase() + "#" + obj.id + "." + obj.className;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Hopefully this helps? :)